# How to correctly use jQuery Isotope + Infinite scroll?

Tags: jquery, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I'm trying to implement isotope + infinite scroll.
The only documentation available at the isotope site is the following code example, and I don't get how does isotope know where to pull data from.
The infinite scroll plugin page doesn't explain much either.

Is it querying the ***nextSelector*** for its href to know where to pull data from?
I don't see that the href of ***#page_nav a*** changes while doing scrolling, so I'm confused about this.
And what is ***navSelector*** used for?

Code in http://isotope.metafizzy.co/v1/demos/infinite-scroll.html :

```
<nav id="page_nav">
  <a href="../pages/2.html"></a>
</nav>

<script src="../js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../jquery.isotope.min.js"></script>
<script src="../js/jquery.infinitescroll.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function(){

    var $container = $('#container');

    $container.isotope({
      itemSelector : '.element'
    });

    $container.infinitescroll({
      navSelector  : '#page_nav',    // selector for the paged navigation 
      nextSelector : '#page_nav a',  // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)
      itemSelector : '.element',     // selector for all items you'll retrieve
      loading: {
          finishedMsg: 'No more pages to load.',
          img: 'http://i.imgur.com/qkKy8.gif'
        }
      },
      // call Isotope as a callback
      function( newElements ) {
        $container.isotope( 'appended', $( newElements ) ); 
      }
    );


  });
</script>
```

Comment: infinitescroll pulls the data, not isotope. How is your #page_nav link set up. Post the html for that.

Comment: The thing is I don't even know what the the *#page_nav* link should be like or what should it do. Currently there's no *link to page n* but a JS code that brings new results when a button is clicked.